# Passar valor variável para dentro de SELECT aninhados

Tags: mysql, select, group-concat

Assumindo a seguinte consulta onde estamos a selecionar valores, a agrupar os mesmos e posteriormente a voltar a agrupar o resultado:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT (b.label, '|', b.slug)
FROM (
    SELECT
        group_concat(name SEPARATOR '$') AS label,
        group_concat(slug SEPARATOR '$') AS slug
    FROM (
        SELECT
            color.name,
            color.slug
        FROM color
        INNER JOIN product__colors USING ( color_id )
        WHERE product__colors.product_id = 1 -- integer fixo funciona
    ) AS a
) AS b
```

Exemplo da saída:

```
azul$vermelho$branco verde|azul$vermelho$branco-verde
```

Mas a consulta é para realizar com o valor de `product__colors.product_id` variável e não `1` como no exemplo em cima:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT (b.label, '|', b.slug)
FROM (
    SELECT
        group_concat(name SEPARATOR '$') AS label,
        group_concat(slug SEPARATOR '$') AS slug
    FROM (
        SELECT
            color.name,
            color.slug
        FROM color
        INNER JOIN product__colors USING ( color_id )
        WHERE product__colors.product_id = ? -- integer variável não funciona
    ) AS a
) AS b
```

## Pergunta

Como podemos passar um valor variável para a condição mais interior ?

Comment: Não ficou muito claro para mim qual o exercício e o que deseja passar da query para a subquery. Suspeito que esta query poderia ser escrita de outra forma para atingir o resultado que gostaria. Mas adiantando, para este tipo de problema, onde a subquery precisa de informações da query, normalmente é usado `JOIN` ou `WHERE`. Veja: http://www.geeksengine.com/database/subquery/correlated-subquery.php

Answer (score 1):

Realmente não ficou claro talvez mas você diz "não executa", eu testei aqui e executou, talvez a forma que esteja declarando a variável esteja dando alguma problema,  essa parte você não demonstrou, segue meu teste.

```
set @variavel = 1;
select 
    CONCAT(b.label,b.slug)    
from (
    SELECT
        group_concat(func_nome SEPARATOR '$') AS label,
        group_concat(func_id SEPARATOR '$') AS slug
    FROM (
        SELECT
            f.func_nome,
            f.func_id
        FROM tab_funcionario f
        INNER JOIN tab_jornada_mot USING ( func_id )
        WHERE tab_jornada_mot.func_id = @variavel -- declarada no inicio do código
    ) AS a
) as b
```

> Fiz algumas alterações nos nomes de tabelas/atributos porque fiz o teste num BD que eu tinha pronto, mas acredito que esteja claro.

Talvez você fez a declaração da variável de outra forma ex:

```
declare variavel int;
select ...
```

Desta maneira não testei, mas conforme acima funciona.